# EJB 3 RemoteInterface class cast exception during lookup

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, remote-access, classcastexception

I am using WebSphere Application Server 8.0.0.1.
I have two enterprise applications running in same jvm (at the moment).

I need to call an EJB-method remotely

1. Application ("service")
   Interface:

   ```
   package myfirstpackage.ejb3;
   @Remote
   public interface TriggerManually {
       public boolean runTask(String taskName);
       public boolean resetTasks();
   }
   ```

   Implementation:

   ```
   package anotherpackage.ejb.remoteclient;
   @Stateless
   public class TriggerManuallyBean implements TriggerManually {
       @Override
       public boolean runTask(String taskName) {
           //Syso...
           return false;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean resetTasks() {
           //Syso...
           return false;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Application ("client") uses the service (the interface is shared)

   ```
   public class TriggerManuallyClient {
     public void test() {
       Properties props = new Properties();

       props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
               "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
       props.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2811");

       TriggerManually triggerManually;
       try {
           InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
           triggerManually = (TriggerManually) ctx
                   .lookup("myjdniname");
           triggerManually.resetTasks();

       } catch (NamingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
   }
   ```

But I get a Class Cast Exception during lookup:

```
Exception created : [java.lang.ClassCastException: myfirstpackage.ejb3._TriggerManually_Stub incompatible with anotherpackage.ejb.remoteclient.TriggerManually
    at anotherpackage.ejb.remoteclient.TriggerManuallyClient.test(TriggerManuallyClient.java:20)
    at com.ibm._jsp._status._jspService(_status.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1147)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:722)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:449)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:919)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:886)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1650)
```

I thougt in EJB 3 i dont have to create stubs. How can I solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the stub (and yes those still exist in EJB3) returned via lookup.

Look carefully at the `ClassCastException`:

`myfirstpackage.ejb3._TriggerManually_Stub incompatible with anotherpackage.ejb.remoteclient.TriggerManually`

You probably have a `TriggerManually` class in package `anotherpackage.ejb.remoteclient` as well.

This will probably fix it:

```
myfirstpackage.ejb3.TriggerManually triggerManually;
try {
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    triggerManually = (myfirstpackage.ejb3.TriggerManually) ctx.lookup("myjdniname");
    triggerManually.resetTasks();

} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just duplicated the interface instead let both ear files use the same...

Answer (score 0):

Clean build your project in Maven.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).